# A Linux Distro/Project for Digital Literacy

Tags: linux

I am in Africa, and I wish to know if there's any project that introduces Linux/Unix to new users?

A project like this one of [Microsoft's on Digital literacy](http://www.microsoft.com/about/corporatecitizenship/citizenship/giving/programs/up/digitalliteracy/default.mspx).

Comment: I wonder if the [OLPC](http://one.laptop.org/) folks have something? Not sure... but a potential lead if you don't get any answers here.

Comment: Also [is there a DIGITAL LITERACY](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313091/is-there-a-digital-literacy) except that that has "Ubuntu" instead of "Linux/Unix".